# Flutter project is not running in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

**Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1**

I have currently latest version chipmunk to run flutter apps in studio.
My project envirnment is,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0 <3.0.0"
```

I tried, Flutter sdk 2.10.0, 2.10.5, 3.0.0, 3.0.5

But, My project is not running on above sdk.
What is reason behind it. Even it is not working after doing flutter pub get.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWcpR.png)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1815 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:349)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:292)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:287)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1429)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:985)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3514)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3507)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2497)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T12GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1629)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 17 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you please share some logs or any error from the console in your question?

Comment: I did not get any kind of error in 3.0.0,3.0.5 flutter sdk. But if I sync 2.10.5 flutter sdk it shows me error that have uploaded in my question.

Comment: Statckoverflow is not allow me to upload image as I'm newbie

Answer (score 0):

delete .idea file , build file and .dart_tool
then

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

try run again

/////////////////////////////////
**UPDATE**

just connected to a random US server.
or

Restarting PC solved issue

> Ref [Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63193)

Comment: I already did that twice. Infact, I restarted my editor and resync sdk but it is still giving me same result.

Comment: is there any signingConfig in android/app/build.gradle ?

Comment: signingConfigs {
//        release {
//            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
//            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
//            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
//            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
//        }
//    }

Comment: Yes, I do have. Bacause, my app is on play store.

Comment: add full terminal error pls

Comment: I have updated my question. please look at that

Comment: look at my update hop this help you

Comment: Still getting same. Even I have updated my Flutter sdk & android studio